# Viewing clang's AST

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I have clang compiling and linking C and C++ code on my Windows system with no problems.  Now I would like to view the AST for my files.  In an older posting on this site the following command line was provided as a solution and it does actually display the AST for my file named test.c:

```
   clang -cc1 -ast-dump test.c
```

There are two issues, however:

1. I searched the clang command line reference document but could find neither the -cc1 nor the -ast-dump option.  Where are these documented?
2. I also found that any of the standard header files I included in my code, such as stdio.h, etc. were not found using the simple command line above (which was not a surprise).  According to the clang command line reference document it seems I should be able to use the -I dir option in the standard way, such as

   -I"C:\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\5.1.0\include\ssp"

   to provide clang with header file location information but that does not seem to work in this case even though header file stdio.h is there.  I also tried the

   -cxx-isystem directory

   option but that didn't work either.

Is there some other document I should be looking at to find out how to do all of this correctly?

Comment: As for the first question: try using `-help-hidden`

Comment: @AlexDenisov - Thanks for the suggestion but apparently this is not supported in the version of clang that I am using (v3.7.0).  It tells me 'unknown argument".

Comment: Try two leading dashes `--help-hidden` ;)

Comment: @AlexDenisov - Yes, the double-dash was accepted and a few additional options were shown.  Unfortunately none of them were those shown in my original question.  Maybe the actual clang source code must be examined to find the actual set of available options.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, there is another option: `clang -cc1  --help`.

Comment: @AlexDenisov - Yes, that did the trick and provided me with all the various options to use with -cc1, including -ast-dump.  It's too bad that there doesn't seem to be a way to determine that -cc1 itself is an option.  Thanks for all your help.